# iOS 14 + vuejs PWA opens camera app instead of displaying video in HTML

Tags: vue.js, progressive-web-apps, ios14

It works as expected on Android, but on iOS it opens camera and only after exiting the camera app it leaves the snapshot in the canvas.

How do I make iOS handle display camera feed in HTML?

I'm posting a (non-functional) fiddle, to illustrate the html and the initialization methods.

https://jsfiddle.net/nz41b2kq/

```
    { some code to appease the SO algorithm }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use "`playsinline`" attribute in the `<video>` element.